# SELECT * FROM small_table executes quickly, returns very slowly in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

I have a small table (~2500 rows, 37 col) being served by Postgrest API. After months of <1sec response times, it's now up to over 20seconds despite the table not being much larger.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE
SELECT * FROM companies

Seq Scan on companies  (cost=0.00..436.93 rows=2393 width=1530) (actual time=0.004..0.860 rows=2393 loops=1)
  Output: <37 column names>
Planning Time: 0.065 ms
Execution Time: 1.311 ms
```

Also

```
CREATE TABLE companies_test as SELECT * FROM companies

OK, Time: 0.076000s
```

For what it's worth, I have also run `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` on the table and it completes in <0.5 seconds

The slow response is seen by the API response time as well as in my Navicat client. According to those two queries above, the query executes as quickly as we'd expect it to, but then delivers the data out of the DB very slowly? I've never encountered this before and am curious if anyone has any ideas of where I could look to resolve this.

Comment: The execution plan clearly shows that the query needs less than 2ms on the server. So whatever slowdown you see is caused by either the network traffic or your application processing 2393 rows.

Comment: Thanks, all the evidence does seem to be pointing towards network issues. It's just tough to accept this because I've got three different data points
Navicat on my machine: >20 sec
Our webapp on Heroku: >20 sec
My coworker's Navicat on local machine: <1 sec

Yesterday all were <1 sec

Comment: Did something change in your application? Maybe the reason is there?

Comment: if you have nginx in front of postgrest, and you have some moderate traffic on your box, this might be the issue https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1399#issuecomment-686327396

Comment: run `netstat -tan | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c` and see if you have a lot of TIME_WAIT connections on the box displaying the problem